# Load `svn export` output into Vinyl stream

Tags: node.js, svn, gulp

For a gulp task, I need to manipulate versioned files (and only those) in my Subversion working copy. Since I'm not aware of any plug-in that can filter out unversioned files from the gulp pipe I'm currently using `child_process.execFileSync()` to run a regular `svn export` command and get my files in a temporary directory. I then feed that directory to `gulp.src()`.

It works and it isn't particularly slow but I'm wondering… Is there a way to skip the file system entirely and create a stream of [Vinyl files](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs) right from `svn export`?

Answer (score 2):

`svn ls [-R] ...`

You have to filter pure directory-nodes from output, but... for nodes without subtrees in it you have clean output immediately without costly file-operations

Comment: This doesn't answer my question but probably solves my problem :) Thank you for the hint, I'll do some research and report back.